# Max length of the CultureInfo.Name property

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0

Maybe somebody knows, what is the possible maximum length of the CultureInfo.Name property in the .NET Framework 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It 11. Here is the code:

```
var count = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
                       .Select(ci => ci.Name.Length)
                       .Max();
```

Comment: Thank you. It is acceptable for me. But it is very strange, Microsoft uses in its Commerce Server 17 characters to store the CultureInfo.Name: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.commerceserver.marketing.languagestring.culturecode(d=lightweight,v=CS.90).aspx

Answer (score 6):

Answer: 84

Documentation: (thanks @lethek in comment)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.cultureandregioninfobuilder%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

I was able to make a new culture using the CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder class that was 84 characters long with the below code.

The CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder will not allow a name longer than 84 characters. To get to 84 characters you need to ensure that each part that you seperate by "-" must be 8 characters or less. You cannot just create a culture called "ThisIsLongerThan8Characters" because it is longer than 8 characters without a seperator. (Note that I think you can use "_" in the same manner, but I've not tried it)

To get the following code working you need to reference the `sysglobl` assembly and import the `System.Globalization` namespace.

The code below tries to unregister the culture at the start and at the end. Once registration is done I load a CultureInfo, format a date and display the Name and DisplayName.

Hope this is helpful.

```
string cultureName = "qwertyui-12345678-qwertyui-12345678-qwertyui-12345678-qwertyui-12345678-qwertyui-123";
Console.WriteLine( "MAX LENGTH: " + cultureName.Length );
try {
    CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Unregister( cultureName );
} catch {
    Console.WriteLine( "Cannot remove culture" );
}

CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder builder = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder( cultureName , CultureAndRegionModifiers.None );

CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo( "en-AU" );
RegionInfo ri = new RegionInfo( "US" );

builder.LoadDataFromCultureInfo( ci );
builder.LoadDataFromRegionInfo( ri );
builder.Register();

CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo( cultureName );

Console.WriteLine( DateTime.Now.ToString( info.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern ) );
Console.WriteLine( info.Name );
Console.WriteLine( info.DisplayName );

try {
    CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Unregister( cultureName );
} catch {
    Console.WriteLine( "Cannot remove culture" );
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - the other answers are incorrect. MSDN explicitly states the maximum possible length is 84 characters (see the remarks section of this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.cultureandregioninfobuilder%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @lethek, I don't remember ever finding any reference to the exact length at the time thus all the code above, so thanks for that. Maybe I just didn't read the that page properly :o)

Answer (score 0):

According the following code :

```
    public static void Test()
    {
        var culturesNames = from c in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
                            select new { c.DisplayName, c.DisplayName.Length, c.Name };


        foreach (var ci in culturesNames.OrderBy((o) => o.Length))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {2} {1}", ci.DisplayName, ci.Length, ci.Name);
        }
    }
```

The max length is 50.
Do not forget a developer can create custom culture info.

Comment: CultureInfo.Name and CultureInfo.DisplayName are the different things. I need the muximum possible length of CultureInfo.Name

Comment: you are right. Simply replace c.DisplayName.Length by c.Name.Length